# Is there a way to deep clone JSoup Document object and get back exactly same HTML?

Tags: java, deep-copy, jsoup

Is there a way to deep clone [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) [Document](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Document.html) object and get back exactly same **HTML**?

I have a pre-parsed object that I want to just clone because I suspect that clone would be faster than always parsing the **HTML** again.

I've tried to clone it by just iterating through of all the elements of the Document object, but then I'm left without the doctype declaration and such.

P.S. I don't of course expect to get the comments...

Comment: Doesn't `Document clonedDoc = (org.jsoup.nodes.Document) origDocument.clone();` work?

Comment: Object.clone() does only a shallow copy, which means that it only copies the reference, so if I manipulate something it will change in both places. I want a deep copy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For any Node you can call .clone()

This was implemented in [feature request](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues#issue/47).

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was afraid of... I'm writing my own cloner but for now I'll just assume the base template and clone head and body separately...

Answer (score 1):

2021. 

As I was confused by the answer and OP's comment on it, here is the result of my humble research :-).

`document.clone()` produces a deep copy of the document object and all of its children. It is true according to [documentation](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Document.html) and my own experiments.
[image]